# Is there a way to get a "union" of several columns of pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am not looking for merging/concatenating columns or replacing some values with other values (although...maybe yes?). But I have a large dataframe (>100 rows and columns) and I would like to extract columns that are "almost identical", i.e. that have >2 values (at the same index) in common and not no different values at other indexes (if there is a value in one column, there must be either the same value or a NaN in the other).
Here is an example of such a dataframe:

```
a = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
b = np.array([np.nan,2,np.nan,3,np.nan,6,8,1,2,np.nan])
c = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
d = np.array([7,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,6,8,np.nan,2,2])
e = np.array([np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,6,8,np.nan,np.nan,2])
f = np.array([np.nan,2,np.nan,3.0,7,np.nan,8,np.nan,np.nan,2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b,'C':c,'D':d,'E':e, 'F':f})
df.ix[3:6,'A']=np.nan
df.ix[4:8,'C']=np.nan
```

**EDIT**

```
keys=['S01_o4584','S02_o2531','S03_o7812','S03_o1122','S04_o5210','S04_o3212','S05_o4665','S06_o7425','S07_o3689','S08_o2371']
df['index']=keys
df = df.set_index('index')

             A    B    C    D    E    F
index                                  
S01_o4584  8.0  NaN  9.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
S02_o2531  8.0  2.0  5.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
S03_o7812  1.0  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
S03_o1122  NaN  3.0  6.0  NaN  NaN  3.0
S04_o5210  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0
S04_o3212  NaN  6.0  NaN  6.0  6.0  NaN
S05_o4665  NaN  8.0  NaN  8.0  8.0  8.0
S06_o7425  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
S07_o3689  8.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
S08_o2371  3.0  NaN  9.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

As you see, columns B, D *(and newly E)* have identical values at locations (indexes) S02_o2531,S04_o3212,S05_o4665 and S08_o2371, whereas at other location, one has a value while the other has s NaN.

My desired output would be:

```
index   BD*E*
S01_o4584   7
S02_o2531   2
S03_o7812   NaN
S03_o1122   3
S04_o5210   NaN
S04_o3212   6
S05_o4665   8
S06_o7425   1
S07_o3689   2
S08_o2371   2
```

However, I can't combine columns that would then have two different values for the same beginning of the index: as you can see, column F also shares some of the indexes, but a new one is at S04_o5210, but the previous combined columns already have a value at "S04_" (index S04_o3212).

Is there a reasonably pythonic way to do it? I.e. 1) find the columns based on the condition that the values in them must be either identical or np.nan, not different. 2) set a condition that a column cannot be combined if it has the same beginning of the index of previously included values (I may probably need to split the string into two columns and do multiindex???) 3) combine them into the new Series/DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

```
def almost(df):
    i, j = np.triu_indices(len(df.columns), 1)

    v = df.values

    d = v[:, i] - v[:, j]
    m = (np.where(np.isnan(d), 0, d) == 0).all(0)

    return pd.concat(
        [
            df.iloc[:, i_].combine_first(
                df.iloc[:, j_]
            ).rename(
                tuple(df.columns[[i_, j_]])
            ) for i_, j_ in zip(i[m], j[m])],
        axis=1
    )

almost(df)

     B
     D
0  7.0
1  2.0
2  NaN
3  3.0
4  NaN
5  6.0
6  8.0
7  1.0
8  2.0
9  2.0
```

***how it works***

- `i` and `j` represent every combination of columns using `numpy` to get the indices of an upper triangle.
- slice the underlying `numpy` array `df.values` with `i` and `j` and subtract them.  Where the differences are `nan`, means one or the other were `nan`.  Otherwise, difference should be zero if respective elements are the same.
- since we can tolerate `nan` in one or the other, fill them with zero using `np.where`.
- find where all rows are zero with `(x == 0).all(0)`.
- use the mask above to slice `i` and `j` and identify the columns that were matches.
- build a dataframe of all matches with a `pd.MultiIndex` for columns that show what matches what.

***cooler example***

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
m, n = 20, 26
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(m, n)),
    columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
).mask(np.random.choice([True, False], (m, n), p=(.6, .4)))

df
```

[image]

```
almost(df)

      A         D    G    H    I         J    K     
      J    X    K    M    N    J    K    V    S    X
0   6.0  7.0  3.0  NaN  4.0  6.0  NaN  6.0  NaN  7.0
1   3.0  3.0  2.0  6.0  4.0  NaN  2.0  6.0  2.0  2.0
2   3.0  0.0  NaN  2.0  4.0  3.0  NaN  3.0  4.0  0.0
3   4.0  4.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  4.0  3.0  3.0
4   7.0  NaN  NaN  7.0  3.0  7.0  NaN  7.0  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  2.0  0.0  5.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
6   NaN  8.0  NaN  NaN  9.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  NaN  8.0
7   NaN  7.0  NaN  9.0  9.0  6.0  6.0  NaN  NaN  7.0
8   NaN  NaN  8.0  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN
9   0.0  0.0  8.0  2.0  NaN  3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  0.0  0.0  NaN  6.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  9.0  3.0  3.0  NaN  3.0  3.0
12  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0  5.0  NaN  5.0  8.0  NaN
13  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  5.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
14  NaN  NaN  6.0  4.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  NaN  0.0  NaN
15  8.0  8.0  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
16  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  6.0  4.0  NaN
17  NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0  2.0  8.0  8.0  4.0  NaN  4.0
18  NaN  NaN  2.0  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
19  NaN  7.0  6.0  3.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  7.0  NaN  7.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanation, this looks like exactly what I wanted! However, somehow I failed at implementation. Your example proves that the method works and that it returns the dataframe of the combined columns (which has fewer columns than the original one). However, when I used it on the data, it returns a much BIGGER dataframe. Any ideas what could be causing this discrepacy?

Comment: @durbachit there is no guarantee that the return dataframe is "smaller".  I'm assuming you mean fewer columns.  for a 10 column dataframe you could end up with a 45 column result if every column matched every other.  With enough columns and sparsity, I'd not expect small number of columns at all.

Comment: Oh I see! It shouldn't be the case that every column matches every other, but there are cases that I have a match between 3-4 columns, not just two. So I would like to combine all these 3 columns into one. A `while` loop inside the function could do the job? (after computing the d, keep looking if there are more with the same parameters)

Comment: @durbachit I'd be careful.  This isn't an equivalence relationship.  Meaning, it isn't transitive.  Meaning you could have `A` match `B`, `B` match `C`, and `C` NOT match `A`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the sticking point is how to detect "almost identical" columns, which are columns that only differ (if at all) in what values are missing. Given two column names, how do you check if they are almost identical? Note that if we find a difference that counts, it must be at an index for which neither column has `NaN`. In other words, the trick is to  **discard rows with a missing value and compare the rest:**

```
tocheck = df[["B", "D"]].dropna()
if all(tocheck.B == tocheck.D):
    print("B, D are almost identical")
```

Let's use this to iterate over all pairs of columns, and merge the ones that match:

```
for a, b in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    if a not in df.columns or b not in df.columns:  # Was one deleted already?
        continue
    tocheck = df[[a, b]].dropna()
    if all(tocheck[a] == tocheck[b]):
        print(b, "->", a)
        df[a] = df[a].combine_first(df[b])
        del df[b]
```

Note (in case you haven't noticed) that when multiple columns end up being merged, it's possible to have order-dependent behavior. For example:

```
     A    B   C
0   NaN   1   2 
1   10   NaN NaN
```

Here you could either merge `B` or `C` into `A`, but not both. Such problems aside, multiple columns can be merged into one since the merged column is saved in place of one of the compared columns.

Comment: Cool! This one works on multiple columns! It doesn't say, however, which ones were combined...But I could just create a list describing which ones were combined together with the new dataframe. Cheers!

Comment: How could I set a condition here to NOT combine the values whose indexes include the same part of a string?

Comment: Say what? I'm not sure what you mean, but if you can detect it, I think it's clear where to put the test. Explain what you need, and if it's not important enough to be a new question I'll add it.

Comment: I know, sorry, it's hard to explain, I hope the example speaks for itself now. (I edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

et voila

```
test = df.B == df.D
df.loc[test,'myunion'] = df.loc[test, 'B']
df.loc[!test ,'myunion'] = df.loc[!test, 'B'].fillna(0) + df.loc[!test, 'D'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Ah, the previous answer got deleted (together with my comment) :(. So once again: I would like to know also the step before that, i.e. how to find out that it's the B and D column that I want to combine. (Search for columns that have the values either identical or value with np.nan - in case there is a different value at the same index, I don't want that.) Thanks. I will edit it in the question to make it clearer.